# Create jar resources while depending on compile and runtime classpath

Tags: java, gradle, jasper-reports

I am trying to compile jasperreports templates together with my java code. To do this I use a private fork of [this plugin](https://github.com/gmazelier/gradle-jasperreports) that is adjusted to work with [gradle properties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/lazy_configuration.html). Now I am trying to find a way to have this plugin provide resources that will be put in the resulting jar file and that are created using the compile and runtime classpaths of the current project.

```
apply plugin: 'com.github.gmazelier.jasperreports'
compileAllReports {
    addClasspath(project.sourceSets.main.compileClasspath)
    addClasspath(project.sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath)
}

sourceSets.main.resources.srcDir compileAllReports
```

addClasspath is implemented as follows:

```
public void addClasspath(FileCollection fileCollection) {
    Provider<List<File>> provider = fileCollection.getElements()
            .map(files -> files.stream().map(FileSystemLocation::getAsFile).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    classpath.addAll(provider);
}
```

where `classpath` is the following property in the task called `compileAllReports`

```
private final ListProperty<File> classpath;

@InputFiles
public ListProperty<File> getClasspath() {
    return classpath;
}
```

My problem is that doing it like that causes the following task dependency cycle:

```
:classes
\--- :processResources
    \--- :compileAllReports
        \--- :classes (*)
```

Is there any way to access the `compile` and `runtime` classpaths without depending on `:classes` (why does a dependeny to `:compileJava` not suffice? The classpaths should already exist a this time) or to add a new resource directory without adding a dependency to `:processResources` (bad idea, because all resources are copied in this task)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem by adding `project.configurations.*Classpath` instead of `project.sourceSets.main.*Classpath`.

Thus my `build.gradle` contained the following code instead of the first section of the question

```
apply plugin: 'com.github.gmazelier.jasperreports'
compileAllReports {
    addClasspath(project.configurations.compileClasspath)
    addClasspath(project.configurations.runtimeClasspath)
}

sourceSets.main.resources.srcDir compileAllReports
```